# How to get the value of On Click events for radio buttons and modify the list accordingly (Java Script)

Tags: javascript

New to Java Script. I have a list of names . Using For loops of the list  and displaying some thing like below.

Name        RadioButton     RadioButton

Name        RadioButton     RadioButton

Name        RadioButton     RadioButton

In the List I have  objects . Once Radio button selected , I wanted to update a field called isEnrolled for that Object (I mean for that Name) accordingly.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.....

Answer (score 0):

Use the event.target.value in your javascript handler.

Comment: You will need to use a radio group and event listener in conjunction with getting and setting value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan. I'm new to JS , will take a look of how event.target.value works .....